# How to display a returned input in Flask using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I've made a simple Flask project with one input and this input has to be returned on the main page with AJAX.

my Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>    
   <div>        
        <div id="questionary">
            <form action='/process' method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                <div>
                    <input type="text"  name="question" id = "question" placeholder="Une question?">
                    <button type="submit"> Pose ta question :) </button>
        </div>
            </form> 
    </div>
        <div>
    <p id="response"></p>
    </div>        
    </body>    
</html>
```

my Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {       
      $.ajax({
         data : {
            question : $('#question').val(),            
                },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/process'
           })           
       .done(function(data) {                 
        $('#response').text(data.output).show();        
     });
     event.preventDefault();
     });     
});
```

My Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify 
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():          
    user_question = request.form['question']
    print(user_question)   
    return jsonify({'response' : user_question})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

Ajax is in /static, html in /templates. 
Desired output is the question asked displayed under the form.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: When running it with an input, the input isn't showing up in `<p id="response"></p>`

Comment: What were you expecting from `data.output`? There's no output field in the JSON response. Maybe try console.log(data) so that you can debug the problem easier

Comment: `console.log(data) ` does show up my input, so I guess my  `$('#response').text(data.output).show(); ` is not written properly.

Comment: Right. You can use the debugging features in Chrome/Firefox to play around with the correct javascript to get what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work if you change:

```
$('#response').text(data.output).show();
```

by:

```
$('#response').text(data['response']).show();
```

data is a json object and this is the proper way to access its values.