# Print a text of textbox in HTML with Flask after pressing a button

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications

This is my first exercise in Flask and I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here.

I want to insert a text in a textbox and then visualize it in `HTML`
I have already looked many answers on StackOverflow, including this:
[Set a python variable in flask with a button and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628640/set-a-python-variable-in-flask-with-a-button-and-javascript)

This is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def my_form():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def func_test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form['Value1']
        return render_template('test.html', value1=text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

and this is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form methods="POST">
<p>Login </p><br>
    <p>Value1 <input type = "text" name = "Value1" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" /></p>

</form>
input is {{value1}}
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like is that after the text is written in the textbox and the button is pressed, the text is printed after `input is`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can wrap your txt result in an if block that only shows when there is value

```
   {% if value %}
   input is {{value1}}
   {% else %}
    input is: 
    {% endif %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<p>Login </p><br>
    <p>Value1 <input type = "text" name = "Value1" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" /></p>

</form>
input is {{value1}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Ade_1 thanks for the answer. What I want is that the text "input is" is always there, and then the input after the button is pressed. At the moment the text is not shown after the button is pressed

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still cant see the input given in the text box. I think there is some error somewhere else

Comment: The problem is in your html, you wrote methods instead of method...

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to accept user input from an HTML form, and return that to the page. As far as I know you're going to need some kind of asynchronous Javascript (aka AJAX) to get this done.

Below is a full example modified from [How to display a returned input in Flask using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60720889/42346) for your situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>    
        <p>Login </p><br>
        <form action='/process' method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <div>
                <p>Value1 <input type="text"  name="value1" id="value1"></p>
                <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
            </div>
         </form>
         <p id="input_is"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Asychronous Javascript/AJAX, put this in a file called `script.js` in your `static` directory:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {       
      $.ajax({
         data : {
            value1 : $('#value1').val(),            
                },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/process'
           })           
       .done(function(data) {                 
        $('#input_is').text(data['response']).show();      
     });
     event.preventDefault();
     });     
});
```

And your Flask route:

```
from flask import jsonify # add to your existing import 

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():          
    user_input = request.form['value1']
    print(user_input) # just for debugging purposes
    return jsonify({'response' : user_input})
```